# MaterializeCSS make rows aligned

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materializecss and I have products in a grid system. Each product is wrapped in a div `<div class="col s12 m6 l4" >` but when the products have varying heights, the products become staggered. I want to make it so that each row is separated and the products align to the left side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it into `.row` class

Example :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s4">Your  Your contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour contentYour content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
   <div class="col s4">Your content</div>
</div>
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/59/)